# Scripting engine for Twilio similar to Tropo

Tags: twilio, tropo

Tropo has a scripting engine using which we can write code in scripting language for voice and sms applications. e.g. the python code to answer a call looks like,

```
answer()
say("thanks for calling")
transfer("tel:+1xxxxxxxxxx")
hangup()
```

Is there something similar available for Twilio. I see that they have Python wrapper over their SDK using which one can do something similar. But I need to find out if there is something similar that Twilio has.

Thanks,
gg

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do anything *dynamic* (respond in different ways based on who is calling), you'll need to provide Twilio with a URL, and then respond with [TwiML](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) at that URL.

You can create TwiML with Python with the helper library: [Creating TwiML with twilio-python](https://twilio-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/twiml.html)

If you are responding to every call in the same way (eg a *static* reply), Twilio has [Twimlets](http://twimlets.com) you can use to create small snippets of functionality, like say a message and then dial a new number. You can host Twimlets with Twilio, so you don't need your own server.